# It's possible auto load or livereload npm run dev

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, vue.js

I want to know if exist some way to live reload or autorun the npm run dev command without type in the shell `npm run dev`

When i use **VueComponents** in **Laravel** with **Webpack Mix**, for *every change in code* i need run `npm run dev` and that proccess is delayed a lot

In the past, i did use ionic, and when i had saved a change the pack is live reload and had build without type nothing in the shell

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- When you create new component/js file and attach it to **Webpack
  Mix** then you need to run

> `npm run dev`

- **Real-time monitor** the changes and compile them

> `npm run watch`

- For **production** mode run

> `npm run production`

- To go back to **development** mode

> `npm run development`

Answer (score 9):

Try running this command:

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Comment: +1 also if you want to run this in the background (in linux) you can add the `&` making it `npm run watch &`

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation of the difference between the two.